# SKScene unarchiveFromFile Method crashing my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

Okay so my app run perfectly fine in the simulator but when I plug in my device and try to run it on the real thing, I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '*** -[_NSPlaceholderData     
initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument'
```

and its due to this method:

```
+ (instancetype)unarchiveFromFile:(NSString *)file {
/* Retrieve scene file path from the application bundle */
NSString *nodePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType:@"sks"];
/* Unarchive the file to an SKScene object */
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:nodePath
                                      options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                        error:nil];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *arch = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
[arch setClass:self forClassName:@"SKScene"];
SKScene *scene = [arch decodeObjectForKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
[arch finishDecoding];

return scene; }
```

More specifically it is caused by the "pathForResource:file ofType:@"sks"
but I dont understand why this causes the error, or how else I am supposed to load my scene and use my app. If it helps, I am using GameScene.h to programatically make my scene, not the scene designer in xcode

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem, but you are using SKScene and GameScene class. Try to use GameScene class in your view controller file to see what will happen.

Comment: what is file? do filenames match, including case?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you want to access a file, which doesn't exists on the real device. Maybe you're accessing a file in a directory which the iOS-simulator can get(in Application Support-folder) but the real iOS device can't.

Check if there are any hard-coded paths in your code which could make this behaviour happen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by avoiding the use of the unarchiving method all together. Previously the scene was created with:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Now I changed that to this and it works fine on the real device:
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

}

Comment: At this way, you did not use the GameScene.sks file.